# Check if a string in java only consists of consonants using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check if a string only consists of consonants, ideally using a regular expression. I've thought of checking only for vowels, however this would mean that all other characters wouldn't be checked. I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
if ( exampleString.matches("[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]") )
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your current pattern matches only if the length of the string is one, try making it repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ( exampleString.matches("[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]+") )
    {
        return true;
    }
```

adding "+" after "[]" means match any consonant char repeated at least 1 time or ideally unlimited times

and that will only match uppercase consonant if you are checking for either upper and lower do this trick

```
if ( exampleString.toUpperCase().matches("[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]+") )
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! Gonna have to do some work on regex it seems :)

Comment: check this book it will make you an expert https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124